# Как использовать классы упакованные Webpack'ом в js коде в браузере?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Понаписывал я много чего используя модули CommonJS, собрал всё это дело с помощью webpack в один файл, но при попытке использовать один из классов в браузере, пишет что такого класса нет. Не понимаю до конца как этим всем счастьем пользоваться.

Pages.ts:

```
export default class Pages {
    ......
}
```

Компилируется в Pages.js:

```
var Pages = (function () {
    function Pages(pathResolver) {
        ......
    }
}());
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = Pages;
```

Собирается в out.js:

```
(function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
          ................................
})
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
var Pages = function () {
    function Pages(pathResolver) {
          ................................
}();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = Pages;
```

Использую так:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>
  var pages = new Pages(null);
</script>
```

При этом получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Pages is not defined(…)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в конфиге webpack добавьте настройку library: nameOfYourLibrary

Данный класс станет доступен как nameOfYourLibrary.default

Comment: не знал про такой конфиг, спасибо

Comment: Прикладываю на всякий случай ссылку на документацию https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html